# Running Seafile within Plesk

Tags: python, apache2, plesk, seafile-server

I'm using Debian 8 alongside Plesk Onyx (latest version). Now I want to install `Seafile`, which is dependent also from Python. I found tutorials on the Internet, however, none which describes how to set this up under Plesk within a subscription. So I neither want the port to be 8080, nor a 'separate' web server by Seafile itself. I want to access my seafile then under https://cloud.mydomain.com, is there any way to do this? And if there's no definite guide, what would be the rough steps (with regard to Seafile's program architecture and how it works)?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if still relevant, but anyway: Yes, it is definitely possible. Seafile installation should proceed according to normal installation process described in [Seafile's Manual](https://www.gitbook.com/book/seafile/seafile-server-manual).

Redirecting the traffic from the frontend servers to Seafile/Seahub is a trickier, a more detailed description, using FastCGI, can be found here:

https://andre-hoeche.de/blog/2016/07/install-seafile-5-1-on-debian-7-10-with-apache-2-2-and-plesk-10-5/